# Getting content of a SOAP Header using Spring WS

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I'm trying to build an endpoint that will receive SOAP messages from a client. The message I'm receiving contains a username and password inside the soap header ...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://www.company.com/Application">
    <soapenv:Header  xmlns:wsse="http://__________.xsd">
        <wsse:Security >
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>

   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
```

I'm using Spring WS - the obvious solution is to create a filter inside `web.xml` that will bypass Spring WS completely, parse the SOAP message, extract the username and password and then continue to Spring WS which will parse the SOAP again.

Is there a way to get the content of the header without circumventing Spring WS?

I've tried adding a bean inside `sws:interceptors`:

```
<sws:interceptors>

    <!-- extract Security details from Header -->
    <bean class="com.company.application.service.SecurityInterceptorService" />

    <!-- log full Body of request -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor"/>

    <!-- validate Request against XSD to make sure it's a valid request -->
    <bean id="CompanyApplication" class="com.company.application.interceptor.ValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/_______________.xsd" />
        <property name="validateRequest" value="true" />
        <property name="validateResponse" value="true" />
    </bean>

</sws:interceptors>
```

and then implementing that class:

```
public class SecurityInterceptorService implements EndpointInterceptor {


    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println("handleRequest")                                             ;
        System.out.println("---------------");


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println("handleResponse");
        System.out.println("---------------");



        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println("handleFault");
        System.out.println("---------------");


        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("---------------");
        System.out.println("afterCompletion");
        System.out.println("---------------");

    }



}
```

`endpoint` only contains data about the endpoint inside `handleRequest` and after traversing through many layers and layers inside `messageContext` while in debug mode, I can't seem to spot the content of the header.

Is the content I'm looking for inside `messageContext` and if so, how do I access it?

Comment: Have a look at the `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/interceptor/SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor.html

Comment: @fateddy, I'll try that as a second-last resort, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [messageContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/context/MessageContext.html) object, you can retrieve either the request or the response (In your case, I guess you need the request).

The request/response is basically a [WebServiceMessage](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/WebServiceMessage.html). If you examine the webServiceMessage, you will see that the object can be casted to a [SoapMessage](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/SoapMessage.html). From the soap message, you can now get the soap header.

```
WebServiceMessage webServiceMessageRequest = messageContext_.getRequest();
SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) webServiceMessageRequest;
SoapHeader soapHeader = soapMessage.getSoapHeader()
```

Afterwards, You might want to get the [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html) object and convert it to a DOMSource object and then get the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) object which make the information retrieval much easier.

```
Source bodySource = soapHeader .getSource();
DOMSource bodyDomSource = (DOMSource) bodySource;
Node bodyNode = _bodyDomSource.getNode();
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks @VirtualTroll ! Didn't know that I had to do some castings to get to the rights stuff.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using spring-boot you can use this kind of configuration:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
    PayloadValidatingInterceptor validatingInterceptor = new PayloadValidatingInterceptor();
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateRequest(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setValidateResponse(true);
    validatingInterceptor.setXsdSchema(resourceSchema());
    interceptors.add(validatingInterceptor);
  }

  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/api/*");
  }

  @Bean(name = "registros")
  public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema countriesSchema) {
    DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
    wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("ResourcePort");
    wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/api");
    wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://resource.com/schema");
    wsdl11Definition.setSchema(resourceSchema());
    return wsdl11Definition;
  }

  @Bean
  public XsdSchema resourceSchema() {
    return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("registro.xsd"));
  }
}
```

In this example the **addInterceptors** method is the important one, the others 3 are basic to expose a WSDL API.

Maybe it'll be useful for someone else.

Comment: What is PayloadValidatingInterceptor here?

Comment: It's an interceptor whose intention is validate that the request fulfils the schema definition

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to unmarshall Soap headers with Spring-ws ([it's currently not supported](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-880))
However, you can access the SoapHeaderElement in your @PayloadRoot annotated method, and do the process of unmarshalling with JAXB.

```
@Endpoint
public class SubmitEndpoint implements EndpointInterface {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.example.com/namespace";

    private Security unmarshallSecurityFromSoapHeader(SoapHeaderElement header) {
        Security security = null;
        try {

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Security.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            security = (Security) unmarshaller.unmarshal(header.getSource());

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return security;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "submit")
    @ResponsePayload
    public SubmitResponse submit(@RequestPayload Submit submit, @SoapHeader(
            value = "{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security") SoapHeaderElement wsseSecurityHeader) throws JAXBException {


        Security security = unmarshallSecurityFromSoapHeader(wsseSecurityHeader);

    }
}
```

**Security.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(namespace = Security.SECURITY_NS, name = "Security")
public class Security {

    public static final String SECURITY_NS = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd";

    @XmlElement(namespace = SECURITY_NS, name = "UsernameToken")
    private UsernameToken usernameToken;

}
```

**UsernameToken.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(namespace = Security.SECURITY_NS, name = "UsernameToken")
public class UsernameToken {

    @XmlElement(name = "Username", namespace = Security.SECURITY_NS)
    private String username;

    @XmlElement(name = "Password", namespace = Security.SECURITY_NS)
    private String password;

}
```